# How to gracefully fallback to `NaN` value while reading integers from a CSV with Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data-processing

While using `read_csv` with Pandas, if i want a given column to be converted to a type, a malformed value will interrupt the whole operation, without an indication about the offending value.

For example, running something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', dtype={ 'my_column': np.int64 })
```

Will lead to a stack trace ending with the error:

```
ValueError: cannot safely convert passed user dtype of <i8 for object dtyped data in column ...
```

If i had the row number, or the offending value in the error message, i could add it to the list of known `NaN` values, but this way there is nothing i can do.

Is there a way to tell the parser to ignore failures and return a `np.nan` in that case?

Post Scriptum: Funnily enough, after parsing without any type suggestion (no `dtype` argument), `d['my_column'].value_counts()` seems to infer the `dtype` right and put `np.nan` correctly automatically, even though the actual `dtype` for the series is a generic `object` which will fail on almost every plotting and statistical operation

Comment: You're explicitly specifying the dtype so it's expecting all values for that column to conform to that type, if you know the values to treat as `NaN` you can pass these to `na_values` however it looks like it's better to just let `read_csv` guess but this will mean that the dtype will be `float64` as `NaN` cannot be represented in `int64`

Comment: Does the `value_counts` indicate some value that would not be convertible to a number? (so that would cause the `object` dtype)

Comment: thanks, your comments led me to the solution, which i posted as answer. you are free to post your alternative answers if you want to add something

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to the comments i realised that [there is no NaN for integers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na), which was very surprising to me. Thus i switched to converting to float:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', dtype={ 'my_column': np.float64 })
```

This gave me an understandable error message with the value of the failing conversion, so that i could add the failing value to the `na_values`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', dtype={ 'my_column': np.float64 }, na_values=['n/a'])
```

This way i could finally import the CSV in a way which works with visualisation and statistical functions:

```
>>>> df['session_planned_os'].dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Once you are able to spot the right `na_values`, you can remove the `dtype` argument from `read_csv`. Type inference will now happen correctly:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', na_values=['n/a'])
```

Comment: Integer values are normally stored in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format, which uses up all available bit patterns on actual numbers.  There are none left over to signify NaN.  By contrast, most floating points are done in [IEEE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which sets aside bit patterns for infinity and NaN.  Note that [floating point values are not precise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate).

Comment: Note that the `dtype={ 'my_column': np.float64 }` is not needed, this should be the result automatically (after you set the correct na_values)

Comment: @joris you are right, thanks. it was necessary in order to get the value of `na_values` though. I will edit my answer