# Pandas read scientific notation and change

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas that i'm reading in from a csv.

One of my columns has values that include `NaN`, `floats`, and scientific notation, i.e. `5.3e-23`

My trouble is that as I read in the csv, pandas views these data as an `object dtype`, not the `float32` that it should be. I guess because it thinks the scientific notation entries are strings.

I've tried to convert the dtype using `df['speed'].astype(float)` after it's been read in, and tried to specify the dtype as it's being read in using `df = pd.read_csv('path/test.csv', dtype={'speed': np.float64}, na_values=['n/a'])`. This throws the error `ValueError: cannot safely convert passed user dtype of <f4 for object dtyped data in column ...`

So far neither of these methods have worked. Am I missing something that is an incredibly easy fix?

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190459/how-to-gracefully-fallback-to-nan-value-while-reading-integers-from-a-csv-with) seems to suggest I can specify known numbers that might throw an error, but i'd prefer to convert the scientific notation back to a float if possible.

EDITED TO SHOW DATA FROM CSV AS REQUESTED IN COMMENTS

```
7425616,12375,28,2015-08-09 11:07:56,0,-8.18644,118.21463,2,0,2
7425615,12375,28,2015-08-09 11:04:15,0,-8.18644,118.21463,2,NaN,2
7425617,12375,28,2015-08-09 11:09:38,0,-8.18644,118.2145,2,0.14,2
7425592,12375,28,2015-08-09 10:36:34,0,-8.18663,118.2157,2,0.05,2
65999,1021,29,2015-01-30 21:43:26,0,-8.36728,118.29235,1,0.206836151554794,2
204958,1160,30,2015-02-03 17:53:37,2,-8.36247,118.28664,1,9.49242000872744e-05,7
384739,,32,2015-01-14 16:07:02,1,-8.36778,118.29206,2,Infinity,4
275929,1160,30,2015-02-17 03:13:51,1,-8.36248,118.28656,1,113.318511172611,5
```

Comment: could you show some data from your dataframe?

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem.  Reading values in scientific notation seems to work fine.  Can you provide a small sample dataset demonstrating the problem?  Are you sure there isn't some other value in the data that is causing the error?

Comment: @BrenBarn, @Anton Protopopov, do you think it's the `Infinity` causing this?

Comment: By "tried to convert the dtype", do you mean you simply typed `df['speed'].astype(float)`?  Because `df['speed'] = df['speed'].astype(float)` should have worked.

Comment: `inf` will work, but not `Infinity`.  There is [a bug report](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10065) asking for support for `Infinity`, but it's not handled yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised it was the `infinity` statement causing the issue in my data. Removing this with a find and replace worked.

@Anton Protopopov answer also works as did @DSM's comment regarding me not typing `df['speed'] = df['speed'].astype(float)`.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without seeing your data but it seems that problem in your rows that they contain something else except for numbers and 'n/a' values. You could load your dataframe and then convert it to numeric as show in answers for [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434208/pandas-converting-to-numeric-creating-nans-when-necessary) question. If you have pandas version >= `0.17.0` then you could use following:

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))
```

Then you could drop row with NA values with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) or fill them with zeros with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using [pandas.round()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) worked.

```
df['column'] = df['column'].round(2)
```