# Read in existing CSV with columns in scientific notation, create new CSV with float

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv

I've read about how you can write a df to CSV in pandas, and suppress scientific notation using:

```
float_format='{:f}'
```

But what about an existing csv with several columns that look like this:

```
FIPS_BLOCK  FIPS_BLKGR  FIPS_TRACT
5.51E+14    5.51E+11    5.51E+10
5.51E+14    5.51E+11    5.51E+10
5.51E+14    5.51E+11    5.51E+10
5.51E+14    5.51E+11    5.51E+10
```

Is there any way to re-write this csv and change these columns to not be scientific notation?  I want them to be eventually strings (in other words, they are numeric, but want them to be text).  I think I need to pass the CSV in pandas, do something, then write it again (overwrite existing CSV).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013790/pandas-read-scientific-notation-and-change) question uses pandas' built in `to_numeric` function to cast entries with scientific notation:

```py
df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))
```

All credit for this solution goes to the author of that answer, @Anton Protopopov

Comment: But some of my fields are not numeric (i.e. string.)  I only want to get numeric for those specific fields which are in scientific notation.

Comment: In that case, I recommend indexing only those columns. So store a list of the numeric columns, and you can say `df[numeric_cols] = df[numeric_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))`

Comment: I tried this.  It's still outputting in scientific notation and I'm pulling my hair out.